# Expected `Result<Option<Value>, Error>`, found `Result<Option<&...>, ...>` on MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, rust, rocket

I have this code to connect with MongoDB from rust run when I try to `cargo run` the code return an error in the if statement and I can't figure out why. It has been days that I try to debug it.
This is the code:

```
use std::iter::FilterMap;
use rocket::serde::json::{json, Value};
use futures::{StreamExt};
use mongodb::{bson::doc, options::ClientOptions, Client};
use bson::{Document};
use warp::body::json;

/**
 * MongoDB client
 */
#[tokio::main]
pub async fn database_connection(key: &str, value: &str) -> Result<Option<Value>, mongodb::error::Error> {

    // uri to connect to the database
    let uri = "mongodb://admin:adminpassword@localhost:27017";
    
    // options to connect to the database
    let mut client_options =
        ClientOptions::parse(uri)
        .await?;

    // Create a new client and connect to the server with the given options
    let client = Client::with_options(client_options)?;

    //Connect to the BinGo! database
    let material = client.database("BinGo!");
    
    // Search thrue a collection
    let collection = material.collection::<Document>("bingo_materials");
    
    let filter = doc! {
        key: value
    };
    
    print!("Making the query to the database...\n");
    
    println!("Filter: {:#?}", filter);
    print!("-------------------------\n");

    let mut cursor = collection.
                find(filter, None)
                .await?;
    
    if let  Some(result) = cursor.next().await {
        println!("{:#?}", result);
        let result_json: &Result<Document, mongodb::error::Error> = &result;
        return Ok(Some(result_json));
    }else{
        return Ok(None);
    }

}
```

and the error is the following:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/databases.rs:57:5
   |
25 |   pub async fn database_connection(key: &str, value: &str) -> Result<Option<Value>, mongodb::error::Error> {
   |                                                               -------------------------------------------- expected `Result<std::option::Option<rocket_dyn_templates::tera::Value>, mongodb::error::Error>` because of return type
...
57 | /     if let  Some(result) = cursor.next().await {
58 | |         println!("{:#?}", result);
59 | |         let result_json: &Result<Document, mongodb::error::Error> = &result;
60 | |         return Ok(Some(result_json));
61 | |     }else{
62 | |         return Ok(None);
63 | |     }
   | |_____^ expected `Result<Option<Value>, Error>`, found `Result<Option<&...>, ...>`
   |
   = note: expected enum `Result<std::option::Option<rocket_dyn_templates::tera::Value>, mongodb::error::Error>`
              found enum `Result<std::option::Option<&Result<bson::Document, mongodb::error::Error>>, _>`
```

Please be kind, I'm new to rust and I'm still learning.

I'm expecting to return the value of `result_json`, because `database_connection()` is called from a route in rocket.rs.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few tips...

I suggest that you `cargo add serde_json` (if you haven't already done that) and then simply convert your `mongodb::bson::Document` into `serde_json::Value`. Here is an example how:

```
if let Some(doc) = cursor.try_next().await? {
    let v = serde_json::to_value(&doc)?;
}
```

You could also add the popular [anyhow](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) crate and make your return type `anyhow::Result<Option<serde_json::Value>>`. Then you could do something like this:

```
if let Some(doc) = cursor.try_next().await? {
    let v = serde_json::to_value(&doc)?;
    return Ok(Some(v));
}
```

Comment: While these are helpful tips, they don't actually *answer the question asked*, as you don't explain why the error is triggered.

Comment: @jthulhu the compiler message seems quite clear to me: the declared (and expected) result type of the function is different from what the function _tries_ to return.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, right now I'm using anyhow to return value and it seems to work but I still have this error on the &doc reference
```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `mongodb::error::Error: Serialize` is not satisfied
   --> src/databases.rs:65:39
    |
    |         let v = serde_json::to_value(&doc).unwrap();
    |                 --------------------  ^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for ```
This is the type`core::result::Result<bson::document::Document,mongodb::error::Error>`

Comment: @EliaTodescato in my example code the type of `doc` is `mongodb::bson::Document`. Be careful not to skip some of the `?`s from my code, as they play a crucial role - they essentially "unwrap" the `Result` value. I don't know what exactly is causing your problems, but it looks to me you're trying to encode a `Result` value as a JSON.